# node_save() is hanging in db_transaction?

Tags: 7, nodes, database

I'm writing some D7 code that handles the modification of a node -- this is happening outside the usual form_submit process, so I'm having to do everything myself.  My basic approach is something like:

```
$the_node = node_load(123);
[change whatever node properties need to be changed]
node_save($the_node);
```

This should be trivial, and works for me in other situations, but, for some reason, in this case it's hanging inside of `node_save`; eventually, my php process reaches its expiration time, and the page times out.  As a test, I've removed all the code that modifies `the_node`, so that all I do is load the node and save it, and it still hangs.

I've put some watchdog statements into `node_save`, and have found that the hang is taking place in that function's initial call to `db_transaction()` -- it goes off to set up the database connection and never comes back.  I realize that this isn't enough information for anybody to really debug what's going on, but I thought I'd post it in the chance that someone else has bumped into this.  Any insights out there?  Thanks!

Comment: Inside which function are you using that code? Is it a hook implementation, or a function that is called from a hook?

Comment: I'm doing an ajax call from a modal form to the server, which runs the code in question.  The overall modal/ajax code has worked well on my site in a number of other situations, so I'm feeling reasonably good about it.

Comment: I'm affraid that helping with it is impossible without MySQL log. It happened to me once, too, but when I mailed hosting company for log, all I got was "We fixed the problem, sorry", and yes, they did, so it *might* be Drupal-unrelated problem there.

Comment: I finally tracked this down; it turned out to be a bug with no particular generality (I was checking some node_access details and went off into a loop).  I'll probably take this note down in a day or so, since there's not much use to it.  But thanks to all for the comments.